# Are the following statements true or false(matrices)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let be $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ matrices.$$(\mathbf{AB})^3=\mathbf{A}^3\mathbf{B}^3$$

1. The left hand side exists but the right hand side doesn't exist.
2. The right hand side exists but the left hand side doesn't exist.
3. Both sides exist but they don't have the same size.

I think that the first and the second statements are true, but I don't know how to prove them.

Comment: Hmm ... I am a little bit confused about the $=$ sign. $(AB)^3=AB\cdot AB\cdot AB$ which is in general not equal to $A^3B^3$. Or are they saying that these are special matrices for which this is true?

Comment: they can be also special matrices, the question is, is there at least one matrix for which these are true

Comment: If we're just checking whether either side exists or not, then we don't need the equals sign. It's just comparing the two expressions: $(AB)^3$ vs. $A^3B^3$. Anyway, what needs to be true for the product of two matrices to exist? What needs to be true for the power of a matrix to exist? You'll need these two facts to check all three statements.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just write down the formats of each matrix. What has to be true for the format of $A$ and $B$ on the left side and what has to be true for the right side.

E.g. For the right hand side. Assume format of $A$ to be $n \text{ x } m$. $B$ has to be $m \text{ x } l$ in order to be able to multiply it with $A$. Additionally from $AB \cdot AB \cdot AB$, we can conclude that $n=l$. Now check if the existance of the left hand side does imply existance of the right hand side.

Comment: Note that $A^n$  and $B^n$ (for any integer n) exist only for A and B **square** matrices.